# Known methods for constant time (table-free) AES implementation using 'standard' operations?

Tags: implementation, aes, side-channel-attack, timing-attack

There are several known methods for implementing AES in constant time using SIMD operations, mostly based around fast byte shuffling (for instance [Hamburg](http://crypto.stanford.edu/vpaes/) and [Kasper/Schwabe](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~ekasper/papers/fast_aes_slides.pdf)). Are there any similar approaches that allow a constant-time AES to be implemented using only standard C operations? The closest thing I've seen is this [byte oriented](http://www.literatecode.com/2007/11/11/aes256/) AES implementation, but it uses input-dependent loops to compute logarithms and exponents for the sbox.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Generally speaking, a lookup-table can be implemented in constant time by doing it as if it was a hardware circuit.

Consider a multiplexer: this is a circuit which accepts three inputs $a$, $b$ and $c$, and yields one output $d$ which is equal to $a$ if $c = 0$, to $b$ otherwise (I am talking about single-bit values here). A multiplexer can be used to implement a $1\rightarrow1$ lookup table: set $a$ to the value of the table for a "0" input, $b$ to the value for a "1" input, and set $c$ to the actual input you want to transform.

If you store single bit values in variables, the corresponding C code looks like:

```
d = (a & ~c) | (b & c);
```

which has a constant execution time.

If you know how to implement $n\rightarrow1$ lookup tables with constant-time code, a $n+1\rightarrow1$ lookup table is obtained by isolating the last bit: you consider the two $n\rightarrow1$ sub-tables, the first one being the table you get by setting the last bit to 0 or 1, respectively. Then you use the outputs of those two sub-tables as $a$ and $b$ inputs for an extra multiplexer controlled by the last input bit. This means that a $n+1\rightarrow1$ table is just a pair of $n\rightarrow1$ tables and extra bit which decides which of the two tables we were actually talking about.

With this construction, a $8\rightarrow1$ table is implementable as a tree of 255 multiplexers like the one above. The AES S-box is an $8\rightarrow8$ table, and is applied to 16 values in parallel at each round, so you end up to having to evaluate $128\times255$ multiplexers per round.

However, with the C code above, you are actually computing *several* multiplexers in parallel. If the C variables are 64-bit values, then you are doing 64 multiplexers simultaneously: bits of index 0 talk to other bits of index 0, bits on index 1 with bits of index 1, and so on, up to bits of index 63. This is known as [bit slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_slicing). Due to the similarity of structure in AES, you can use that to reduce the number of multiplexer evaluations to $4\times 255$ per round: a mere thousand...

With such techniques, you can end up with a constant-time, plain C implementation of AES which should evaluate a block in, say, 20000 clock cycles. Which is awfully slow, but still doable. However, this is only the beginning. There are many optimizations which can be applied to such a structure (e.g. you can replace multiplexers with a not-exactly-a-multiplexer construction "`a ^ (b & c)`", which selects between $a$ and $a \oplus b$ ($a$ xor $b$), and is enough to implement a lookup table; also, the first row of multiplexers in a tree can often be collapsed since its inputs are known values of 0 or 1). For the DES S-boxes (eight distinct $6\rightarrow4$ tables), very optimized bitsliced implementations were designed by [Matthew Kwan](http://www.darkside.com.au/bitslice/) back in 1998. Moreover, the AES S-box has an internal algebraic structure which can probably be further exploited.

A google search on "bitslice implementation AES" links to a few research papers, but apparently none being publicly downloadable.

Answer (score 11):

Just to complement Thomas's reply, here are a couple of papers that do not rely on SIMD registers to implement bitsliced AES:

- [How Far Can We Go on the x64 Processors?](http://www.iacr.org/archive/fse2006/40470344/40470344.pdf) (source in appendix)
- [A Fast and Cache-Timing Resistant Implementation of the AES](http://books.google.com/books?id=uatika8-01oC&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=x64%20bit%20slice%20aes&source=bl&ots=qgqH_oTbsA&sig=DUwkVhiE60JZM5ubhhiPlB1vdWw&hl=en&ei=OrxOTqGdHdCZhQezoJXLBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=x64%20bit%20slice%20aes&f=false) ([source code](http://www.iaik.tugraz.at/content/research/krypto/aes/bitsliced_aes.tar.gz))

Answer (score 8):

Adding to Thomas's answer: in [*A depth-16 circuit for the AES S-box*](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/332), Joan Boyar and Rene Peralta give a compact representation of AES tables as boolean operations, that are useful for a bitslice/SIMD implementation.